Jetpack Compose - Recomposition invoked with key properly set when child receives list
(All code is simplified)
I have this call in my @Composable function
Column {
    for (song in songs) {
        key(song.id) {
            SongRow(song = song)
        }
    }
}

If Song is data class defined like this
private data class Song(
    val id: Int,
    // val flags: List<String>
)

Recompositions are not invoked when I shuffle "songs". But if I uncomment flags, SongRows will be recomposed with every change. Why is that?

In the first case, you are passing a unique key id to the loop and hence when you shuffle, it will not get recomposed.
In the second case, you introduce a list in the Song class. In compose, a list is always considered unstable. That is why you are facing recomposition on every change.

List<T> is always considered "unstable" by the compose compiler, to help fix this you can annotate the Song class with @Stable or replace the use of List<String> with ImmutableList<String> from this library:
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable
To learn more about the concept of stability in compose and how it works i recommend you check out these links.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/performance/stability
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/performance/stability/fix

I was sure List is immutable in the eyes of Compose compiler and didn't read about stability before. Your answer helped a lot. Thanks
